# Finding date within date range

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to find all documents with date field within date range as shown below in my Meteor app, but for some reason it is always returning empty records, can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong / missing here? Thanks

Sample document:

```
_id: "tMSfNq9JR85XDaQe5"customerid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr"date: Sun Dec 07 2014 19:50:21 GMT+0800 (HKT)description: "Test"
```

Tried using queries from Chrome console as follows:

```
Custlog.find({date: {$gt: new Date(2014, 12, 1) , $lt: new Date(2014, 12, 10) }}).fetch()

Custlog.find({date: {$gt: new Date(01/12/2014) , $lt: new Date(10/12/2014) }}).fetch()
```

Comment: can you narrow the scope of your debugging by looking into mongod log file and verify what query is actually transmitted to mongod? and then get a this query to work from mongo shell directly against mongod.These are good first steps

Comment: @alernerdev I am using Meteor so I don't have direct access to monogd. I've tried searching if it is possible to get access to mongod while using Meteor but couldn't find any info

Comment: My guess is your documents may not be published. Do you get anything back with `Custlog.find().fetch()`? To access the mongo shell run `meteor mongo` from the command line in the same directory as your project while your project is running.

Comment: @MChan, did my answer below, give you what you need to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their infinite wisdom, the implementors of the JavaScript Date Object made the month field zero indexed. So, January 1 is `new Date(2014, 0, 1)` and December 1 is `new Date(2014, 11, 1)`. What you have `Date(2014, 12, 1)` is actually January 1, 2015.

Similarly, `new Date(01/12/2014)` is equivalent to dividing 1 by 12 and then dividing that by 2014 and then sending that as a number to the date object which is zero so it should give you the Unix Epoc, which in your time zone (GMT+08) is January 1, 1970.

Comment: Just to be explicit: Custlog.find({date: {$gt: new Date(2014, 11, 1) , $lt: new Date(2014, 11, 10) }}).fetch() would give you the documents with dates greater than december 1st and less than december 10th.